# How do I subclass collections.Iterator?

Tags: python, collections, iterator, abc

According to the documentation on [ABCs](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#abcs-abstract-base-classes), I should just have to add a `next` method to be able to subclass `collections.Iterator`.  So, I'm using the following class:

```
class DummyClass(collections.Iterator):
    def next(self):
        return 1
```

However, I get an error when I try to instantiate it:

```
>>> x = DummyClass()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class DummyClass with abstract methods __next__
```

I'm guessing that I'm doing something stupid, but I can't figure out what it is.  Can anyone shed some light on this?  I could add a `__next__` method, but I was under the impression that was only for C classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you are using Python 3.x. Your code works fine on Python 2.x.

```
>>> import collections
>>> class DummyClass(collections.Iterator):
...     def next(self):
...         return 1
... 
>>> x = DummyClass()
>>> zip(x, [1,2,3,4])
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)]
```

But on Python 3.x, you should implement `__next__` instead of `next`, as shown in the table of [the py3k doc](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html). (Remember to read the correct version!)

```
>>> import collections
>>> class DummyClass(collections.Iterator):
...     def next(self):
...         return 1
... 
>>> x = DummyClass()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can’t instantiate abstract class DummyClass with abstract methods __next__
>>> class DummyClass3k(collections.Iterator):
...     def __next__(self):
...         return 2
... 
>>> y = DummyClass3k()
>>> list(zip(y, [1,2,3,4]))
[(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

This change is introduced by [*PEP-3114 — Renaming `iterator.next()` to `iterator.__next__()`*](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/).

Comment: It must be a bug with Python 2.6.1 on the Mac then.

Comment: Just to clarify my last comment, I *am* running python 2.x.  It seems to have been fixed in a version after the version that ships with OS X.

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary to inherit from the `Iterator` class to make the object iterable. But in my case that was required, so did it like this:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterator

class MyIterator(Iterator):

    def __init__(self, items, property1, property2):
        self.items = items
        self.property1 = property1
        self.property2 = property2
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.items.__iter__()

    def __next__(self):
        return self.items.__next__()
```

The test code is:

```py
my_iterator = MyIterator([1, 2, 3], "value 1", 2)

for item in my_iterator:
    print(f'{item} ', end='')
print()
print(my_iterator.property1)
print(my_iterator.property2)
```

And the output is:

```sh
1 2 3
value 1
2
```

The documentation is: [class `collections.abc.Iterator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterator)